# Excel File Schema

Tags: mysql, database, excel, documentation-generation

I have an excel file in which I have documented the database dictionary. Each table is documented under following major columns:

**Name
Fields
Comments
Count**

I want to generate a visual schema of this documentation - something catchy like expanding tables etc for each db table. Is there anything (an application) I can use in this regard? Or, is there some code that I can write to generate this schema? there are more than 500 tables.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

For instance, let me give you example of a single table:

```
Table_A     Field_1      Field_1 description
Table_A     Field_2      Field_2 description
Table_A     Field_3      Field_3 description
[blank row]
Table_A     Info         Table Description
Table_A     Info         Table Requirements
```

So, that's one table. 'Table_A' serves as an identifier for all its fields and info rows.

Comment: i know of some enterprise level applications that can ingest this data, then turn it into diagrams (and lots of other meta-data type reporting) e.g. www.enterpriseelements.com - you should first decide on the actual output you want

Comment: I would think Excel would be able to display this information in an intuitive way with pivot tables. Can you give an example of how you have the data dictionary formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I would say a pivot table would be a decent way to summarize a data dictionary:

[image: PivotTableDataDictionarySummary]

Comment: thanks stephan..I think its a much simpler way to achieve this object.